# How to debug what changes textfield text during route change?

Tags: angularjs

### How to debug what changes textfield text in angularjs?

I have a bug. I am on page 1, which has email field. I change email in that field and click link to go to another page (route changes). Then I go back to page one and I see change which I made to email field is not there - it shows old email.

```
if(typeof policyReference.user.email !== 'undefined') {
    $scope.allData.user.email = policyReference.user.email;

    // for vopins when agent buys:
    // this is for setting email on page refresh. But it makes set it also when going step back. So commented.
    // Need to find how to make it set on page load and not set on going back.

    $scope.allData.policy_holder['checkout[policy_holder][email]'] = policyReference.user.email;
    console.log('this is not called on route change');
    handlePaymentProfiles(policyReference.user.email);

    if (partialAccountSetup) {
        $scope.allData.account_setup['checkout[account_setup][signup][email][first]'] = policyReference.user.email;
        $scope.allData.account_setup['checkout[account_setup][signup][email][second]'] = policyReference.user.email;
    }
}
```

I found which line is causing a bug but I dont understand why it is causing. Line is this:

```
$scope.allData.policy_holder['checkout[policy_holder][email]'] = policyReference.user.email;
```

I cannot remove this line because I need it so that email would be set on all application load.

I have tried to add logic something like - if it is page load, then run this line. Otherwise not. But looks like that line is only executed on page load. But somehow is causing bug on route change.

I need ideas where to look for. How to detect which code is changing input field text? I tried debugging with chrome debugger but I dont see the line being changed on our code, but it feels like by something in the angularjs code which is super hard to debug.

**Update:**

I have made a small script which kind of show the reseting on view change.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.view1', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/view1', {
    templateUrl: 'view1/view1.html',
    controller: 'View1Ctrl'
  });
}])

.controller('View1Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.email  = 'a'; 
}]);
```

And I have tried setting breakpoint on 
      $scope.email  = 'a';

and on load and each time I go to /view1 route, it stops on the breakpoint which makes sense and is debuggable.

But in my real application - it does not stop on route change at line which causes problem:

```
$scope.allData.policy_holder['checkout[policy_holder][email]'] = policyReference.user.email;
```

Why could that be?

I also have added to my real project the code

```
this.$onInit = function() {
        console.log("View controller initialization");
        //Restore data here
        //...
    };

    this.$onDestroy = function() {
        console.log("View controller teardown");
        //Save data here
        //...
    };
```

It is only one controller for both routes. And I do not get teardown log message. I only get init "View controller initialization" and it is only on page load, then I can change routes many times and no more messages. So kind of looks like controller is not destroyed.

Comment: Be aware that route changes destroy both the controller and the scope of the view. Data that needs to persist between route changes should be stored in a service.

Comment: @georgeawg - by service you mean what ? Some additional js file which is called a service and add it as dependency to controller? But probably this will also be destroyed. Or service you mean backend? Or some local storage maybe? I am not sure how other fields are solved in our project. Btw same contrller in our project is used for many routes. So even then they are not stored in controller scope? Oh - and btw - if data is destroyed, why input field could not be empty but is prefiled with old value? At least I dont see it calling same function as on page load which loads the data to the fields

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that route changes destroy both the controller and the scope of the view. Data that needs to persist between route changes should be stored in a service.

One approach to dealing with the destuction of the controller is to add teardown code in the `$onDestroy` life-cycle hook:

```
app.controller("viewController", function() {
    this.$onDestroy = function() {
        console.log("View controller teardown");
        //Save data here
        //...
    };
    this.$onInit = function() {
        console.log("View controller initialization");
        //Restore data here
        //...
    };
})
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference - Life-cycle hooks](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#life-cycle-hooks)

---

> by service you mean what ?

```
app.service("viewdata", function() {
    var email;
    this.setEmail = function(val) {
        this.email = val;
    };
    this.getEmail = function() {
        return email;
    });
})
```

Services are singletons which last for the lifetime of the app.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Creating Services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services#creating-services)